# Dividing long application to Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a process running every night and doing lot of data analysis for a set of companies . I am doing this just in a for loop that runs through company list . Sometimes It takes about 1 hour for this process to completed . Sometimes cause of some errors it crashes in between causing . I have to manually restart it and it processes all remaining company's analysis .

Since each for loop run's a separate company's data analysis should multithreading inside for loop be a good solution?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Creating a lot of threads will not necessarily speed up the process; you need to use them wisely. Take a look at Java's high level concurrency: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html

Comment: Don't go near multithreading until you have fixed your existing bug/s and error-handling!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) is your friend!

Comment: For posterity, can you please edit your question to provide more information?  Why is it good?

Answer (score 2):

> Since each for loop run's a separate company's data analysis should multithreading inside forloop be a good solution ?

Maybe yes, maybe no.

Lets look at the facts:

> Sometimes It takes about 1 hour for this process to completed

By itself, this should not be a problem.  One hour is not a long time, especially since you probably have a ~12 hour window to do it.

And multi-threading won't *necessarily* significantly reduce the elapsed time.  It depends on the nature of tasks, the processing algorithms, and the nature of your hardware and system configurations.

> Sometimes cause of some errors it crashes in between causing (what?).

Multi-threading won't fix that.  If you do each company run in a separate thread, then the same error would still cause that thread to crash.  And depending on the *cause* of the error, and the *consequences* of the error, the crash for one company could crash the others too ... or cause them to work incorrectly in other ways.

> I have to manually restart it and it processes all remaining company's analysis.

Threading won't entirely fix that either.

You'll still have to to fix the problem(s) that caused the original crash(es) and then manually restart.  And you still have the problem of distinguishing and recording the companies that need to be rerun so that you don't repeat the other unnecessarily.

In summary, multi-threading could make the application go faster (it probably will IMO), but I don't really think it is going to solve your root problem ... which appears to be either bad data or bugs causing processing to fail.

---

Finally, on a technical level, it is probably a bad idea to simply fire off a thread for each company.  If you try to do the work in parallel, the threads will be competing for local resources and resources on your back-end database.  It is probably better to use something like ThreadPoolExecutor with a limited pool size.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a wrapper for error handling... log it and proceed incase of errors... in that way you don't have to restart incase of errors.

```
for( your company list){
try{
    your tasks
}catch(Exception){
//log error and proceed
```

}

Are your tasks independent for your company list? 
If so, you can create new thread to process each task..
If not, you can process them sequential in required order